# Access Delphi Android app documents via USB

Tags: android, delphi

My Delphi Android app uses:

```
System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.IOUtils.TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + kFolderNameRootData
```

It reports the location of the documents as:

```
/data/data/com.bookup.chessopeningswizardexpress/files/Chess Openings Wizard 2016/
```

I've tried viewing this folder using the Windows 10 File Explorer:

```
This PC\Fire\Internal storage\Android\data\com.bookup.chessopeningswizardexpress\files
```

But it does not contain the documents.

How do I move documents back and forth from my Delphi Android app using Windows 10?

Comment: `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` returns a path that is private to your Android app and not accessible to the outside world.  Try using `TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath` or `TPath.GetPublicPath` instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks.

My question still stands though. How do I share documents with the outside world, documents that are edited in that private folder?

Comment: You can't, they are private, only your app can access them.  I think you need to read up on how Android's storage system works. See [Save Files on Device Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html) and [Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms).

Comment: My competitors apps are moving their documents into and out of the editing folder using Dropbox. There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: GetSharedDocumentsPath returns 
/storage/emulated/0/Documents
GetPublicPath returns
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bookup.chessopeningswizardexpress/files

Both of those folders appear to be empty when I use the app to list their contents.

I cannot glean from the Android documentation whether (or how) files can be moved into and out of these folders.

Comment: I don't care what your competitor's app does. If you want your files to be accessible to the PC, YOUR app needs to save the files in a publicly accessible folder, and that is not `GetDocumentsPath`. Android's documentation is very clear on this. If `TPath` can't get you a path to such a folder, then use Delphi's JNIBridge framework to access Android's APIs directly. See [Save Files on Device Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html) in Android's documentation for more details.

Comment: I'm looking a three different components that use Dropbox. 

While it's clear that nothing outside my app will ever be able to access my app's private directory, I'm still unable to find a call that returns a shared folder. 

I don't know what a "JNIBridge" is. I was hoping to get something working without jumping through hoops like using the Android API directly.